# Logic for if NOW is between two date-times

Tags: javascript, date, date-fns

I am building a schedule for a radio show and i need to show which show is currently live.
At the moment it is working from the start hour but still shows "live" **after** the end hour.

[image]

This screenshot is taken at 10:12am

i am using the `date-fns` library.
the schedule data shape is as follows.

```
"shows": [
    {
      "artist": "Set & Setting ",
      "starts_at": "2020-06-29T07:00:00.000Z",
      "ends_at": "2020-06-29T08:00:00.000Z",
      "description": "w/ JD"
    },
    {
      "artist": "Set & Setting ",
      "starts_at": "2020-06-29T08:00:00.000Z",
      "ends_at": "2020-06-29T09:00:00.000Z",
      "description": "w/ JD"
    },
    {
      "artist": "The Great Stuff",
      "starts_at": "2020-07-16T21:00:00.000Z",
      "ends_at": "2020-07-16T13:00:00.000Z",
      "description": "w/ ??"
    },
    {
      "artist": "The Melting Pot ",
      "starts_at": "2020-07-16T17:00:00.000Z",
      "ends_at": "2020-07-16T19:00:00.000Z",
      "description": "w/ Tom B"
    }
  ]
```

My logic for working out if the current item in the iteration is live is

```
...
import { startOfToday, parseISO, getHours, getMinutes, sub } from "date-fns"
...

const now = new Date();
const { starts_at, ends_at } = item;
const liveNow =  (
        (getHours(now) >= getHours(parseISO(starts_at)) && getMinutes(now) >= getMinutes(parseISO(starts_at))) &&
        (getHours(now) <= getHours(parseISO(ends_at)) && getMinutes(now) <= getMinutes(sub(parseISO(ends_at), { minutes: 1 })))
);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try to use:
Before version 2.0.0:

`isWithinRange(date, startDate, endDate)`

Example:

```
const liveNow = isWithinRange(now, parseISO(starts_at), parseISO(ends_at))
```

After 2.0.0:

`isWithinInterval(date, interval, [options])`

Example:

```
const liveNow = isWithinInterval(
  now,
  { start: parseISO(starts_at), end: parseISO(ends_at) }
)
```

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you i will give it a go! 
For some reasonm that function is hard to find on the `date-fns` documentation. 
Have found it now!

Comment: Cool... I hope it will work... And vote up if everything was ok. Have a great day.

Comment: `isWithinRange` does not exist on `date-fns:v-2+` but `isWithinInterval` does which is what they renamed it to! Thanks for your help.

Comment: I've updated the answer with both versions for other users.